# C simple error in coding - Error E0144 - How can i make the code working?

Tags: c

I tryed to make a program to show the output "f" after executing the code. The result was the error E0144 after trying this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char first_ch = "f";
    printf("%c", first_ch );
    return 0;
}
```

and after trying this the result was 0:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char* first_ch = "f";
    printf("%c", first_ch );
    return 0;
}
```

Can you explain me why is showing this error at first and after that why in the second case the output is 0 and after all, what should i type to make the program work like i want?
Thank you very much!

Comment: What is error E0144?  Include the text of the error message.

Comment: read about `printf` format specifiers. There are different specifiers for different data types

Answer (score 2):

In C, the char data type uses single quotes ' ' instead of double qoutes " ".

try running

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char first_ch = 'f';
    printf("%c", first_ch );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first situation, try using single quotes, such as 'f'. This seems to work. I think in C, **there seems to be a rule such as single-quotes for single characters, and double quotes for strings**. Not sure why though.

*char first_ch = 'f';*

For the second situation, you're going to need the library <stdlib.h>. "const char*" is going to create an array of chars via malloc(). **They are initially given the value of "0".** I'm not sure, but I don't think using the keyword "const" is a good idea at initialization, it results in the default value (0) being unable to be modified (as far as I know).

I'd say, the first situation is simpler and gets the job done.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanations and the set up you made!